# Taskbar aeropeek preview and Alt-Tab auto close on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, aero, aero-peek

I wanted to reply to the following thread:
[taskbar icon preview (and Alt+Tab icon preview) disappears quickly](https://superuser.com/questions/770881/taskbar-icon-preview-and-alttab-icon-preview-disappears-quickly?newreg=ffef50a9873d477d8fb2c4283ece7eaa)

But I am not allowed to. So I am created another here to share my experience.

First, the Behaviour
 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
When you move over the application icon on the taskbar (that has application opened), you would expect a preview to appear. In this case, although the preview window appears, it will simply auto-disappear (i.e. closed by itself within a very short period of time, e.g. 1s). This behaviour is also evident when you use Alt-Tab.

Very frustrating!

Editing the registry, etc, does not help for me. Setting the aero peek (enable or disable or a mixture of those) also does not help.

Comment: Hi Jacky, the expected format here would be writing a question and adding an own answer. Since this would become a duplicate (and closed as such) of the question you referenced, maybe the best would be to remove this question.

Comment: You now have 10 reputation, and as such, can post an answer on the original question. I think the best course of action would be to move your solution to an answer on that question and delete this question.

Comment: Hi Jacky, since you now able to answer there, please do, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I have updated and formatted as such, thanks again!

Comment: Please do not add "SOLVED" to the title. You will be able to select your answer as the solution. This will automatically indicate the question has a solution. Therefore, no need to add it to the title.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution
~~~~~~~~~
After trying different ways, I found out that it was due to the battery charging setting!!! - A ridiculously stupid cause.

I believe this is a bug, but if it is not categorized as such, then I supposed the aero peek might be taking too much battery or whatever that the battery setting was configure to close it.

I am using Lenovo T440s. So all I did was to change it back from "Optimize for battery health" to "Always full charge (Start when below 96%; stop at 100%)".

Hope this help those who find the other solutions not working.

GLATB.

Regards,
Jacky

Comment: Hi Jacky, please answer on the original [question](http://superuser.com/q/770881/172747) and remove these, it'll be closed as duplicate.